# jQuery sticky navigation not animating back quickly enough

Tags: jquery, css

I've put together a "sticky navigation" using jQuery and CSS. The navigation animates and slides down from the top of the screen once the user has scrolled past a certain point.  That works fine.

What I want to do is have it animate and scroll back up out of sight when the user scrolls back past the same point at which the navigation slid down.  Once they get back up to the top of the page the navigation should be there at the top as normal. This is half working, however the navigation doesn't animate completely out of sight until the user is right back up at the top of the page, which is ruining the illusion.

What do I need to do to get it to correctly animate out of sight on the scroll back up?

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nav = $(".header-main");
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = 100;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top
        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
            if (!nav.hasClass('header-main-sticky')) {
                nav.addClass("header-main-sticky").css({
                    top: '-100px'
                }).stop().animate({
                    top: '0px'
                }, 500);
            }
        } else {
            if (nav.hasClass('header-main-sticky')) {
                nav.stop().animate({
                    top: '-100px'
                }, 500, function() {
                    nav.removeClass("header-main-sticky").css({ top: '0px' });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Full example here](http://jsfiddle.net/svz6h1eg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend changing this part:

```
if (nav.hasClass('header-main-sticky')) {
   nav.stop().animate({top: '-100px'}, 500, function() {
      nav.removeClass("header-main-sticky").css({ top: '0px' });
   });
}
```

to this:

```
if (nav.hasClass('header-main-sticky')) {
   nav.removeClass("header-main-sticky").css({ top: '0px' });
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nav = $(".header-main");
  var sticky_navigation_offset_top = 80;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top
    if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
      if (!nav.hasClass('header-main-sticky')) {
        nav.addClass("header-main-sticky").css({
          top: '-100px'
        }).stop().animate({
          top: '0px'
        }, 500);
      }
    } else {
      if (nav.hasClass('header-main-sticky')) {
        nav.removeClass("header-main-sticky").css({
          top: '0px'
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.header-main {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #808080;
}
.header-main-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-main">&nbsp;</div>

<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
<p>Scroll down</p>
```

Comment: This doesn't really help - I want the navigation to animate back up before the user gets back to the top of the page.  The reason being is because when the navigation slides down it's styled differently to the full navigation that the user sees at the top.